# Generalization of Opperman's Conjecture

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps, sieve-theory, distribution-of-primes

Does this conjecture have a name? What about a counterexample?:

$$ \forall n,k \in \mathbb{N}, k \gt 1, \exists d \in (kn-n,kn] \text{ s.t. } d \perp n! $$

An equivalent statement is this:

Take a Sieve of Eratosthenes-like list of any fixed width $n$ and sieve out multiples of the primes $\leq n$. While keeping the width fixed, let the length of the list extend to infinity. In every row there is an unsieved number (a number that is coprime to all the primes $\leq n$).

Note that for $k \leq n+2$, $d\perp n!$ is necessarily prime. Bertrand's Postulate sets $k=2$. Legendre's conjecture is about the union of rows $n+1$ and $n+2$. Opperman's conjecture is each of these rows individually. This generalization would extend Opperman to any row whatsoever (except the first).

Results to date: Erdos et. al. proved Bertrand. Legendre and Opperman are open. Prime sieves like this one are cyclic in nature, with the distribution of primes repeating every $\prod^{n}_{p \perp n} p$ rows. Ive checked by hand all possible rows in all the possible widths $\leq$ 7.

Examples of sieves:

$n = 5$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & \color{grey}{2} & \color{grey}{3} &  & \color{grey}{5} \\ \hline
 & 7 &  &  &  \\ \hline
11 &  & 13 &  &  \\ \hline
 & 17 &  & 19 &  \\ \hline
 &  & 23 &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  & 29 &  \\ \hline
31 &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 & 37 &  &  &  \\ \hline
41 &  & 43 &  &  \\ \hline
 & 47 &  & 49 &  \\ \hline
 &  & 53 &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  & 59 &  \\ \hline
61 &  &  &  & \color{white}{65} \\ \hline
\end{array}

$n = 6$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & \color{grey}{2} & \color{grey}{3} &  & \color{grey}{5} & \\ \hline
7 &  &  &  & 11 &\\ \hline
13 &  &  &  & 17 &\\ \hline
19 &  &  &  & 23 &\\ \hline
 &  &  &  & 29 &\\ \hline
31 &  &  &  &  &\\ \hline
37 &  &  &  & 41 &\\ \hline
43 &  &  &  & 47 &\\ \hline
49 &  &  &  & 53 &\\ \hline
 &  &  &  & 59 &\\ \hline
61 & \color{white}{62} & \color{white}{63} & \color{white}{64} & \color{white}{65} & \color{white}{66}\\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: For $k=2$ it is a consequence of Bertrand's postulate (assuming that by "$\ni$" you mean "and").

Comment: I take $\ni$ to mean "such that". Although and sort of works there.

Comment: Added your Bertrand example and changed it to "such that".

Comment: Do you know what the reason was for Opperman and Legendre to target these rows in particular?

Comment: Maybe because these are the last rows where "coprime to all p $\leq$ n" is equivalent to "prime".

Comment: If counterexample exist, it would mean $n$ consecutive $n$-smooth numbers. Stormer's theorem may be a good starting point for it.

Comment: maybe my notation is bad. I mean to say for all n and for all k, $\exists d \perp n!$ s.t. $(kn - n) < d < kn$ where $d$ is a number coprime to $n$!. For $k > n+2$, d is not necessarily prime.

Comment: ok, there was a serious flaw in the logic. p might divide ${kn\choose n}$ without implying that one of those integers is coprime to n. I kept $\forall n,k$ to mean for all n, for all k though.

Comment: The counterexample for changed statement is $n=2$, $k=5$. No prime $p$ exist such that $8<p<10$. Also, $n<p<2n\le kn$ does not lead to $p \mid \binom{kn}{n}$, for example, consider $n=2$, $p=3$ and $k=4$.

Comment: @didgogns p is not necessarily prime, just coprime to n!. In the case you cite, 3$^2$ is coprime to 2.

Comment: changed p to d for clarity.

Comment: @DavidDiaz true, deleted ...

Comment: See related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3465494/the-crosshatch-conjecture-on-primes-in-p-p2. I'd bet everything this one holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture does not hold for $n=8, k=25$ as all $8$ numbers
$$(201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208)$$ have factors less than $8$, which are $(3, 2, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2)$ respectively.

For prime $n$, smallest counterexample is $n=13, k=168$ because all $13$ numbers$$2185, 2186, \cdots, 2197$$have factors less than or equal to $13$, which are $(5, 2, 3, 2, 11, 2, 7, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 13)$.

I thought your conjecture is true before running a program because intuitively $\prod_{p_i\le n} (p_i-1)/p_i$, which is the ratio of numbers left on each stage of Sieve of Eratosthenes decreases much slower than the growth of $n$.